# Sumar valores dentro de NGFOR

Tags: angular, angular-directivas

Me gustaría un poco de ayuda. Estoy generando una tabla dentro de un **`ngFor`**, pero necesito mostrar en el **`footer`** de la misma la sumatoria de cierto campo:

```
<div *ngFor="let pista of prize.pistas">
    <div>
        <h2>{{ pista.numero_pista }}</h2>
    </div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>
                <h5>Prueba</h5></th>
            <th>
                <h5>Inscritos</h5></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let p of pista.pistas;">
                <td>
                    <strong>
                                    {{ p.prueba }}
                                </strong> {{ p.nombre }}
                    <strong *ngIf="p.categoria != null">
                                    {{ p.categoria }}
                                </strong>
                </td>
                <td>{{ p.cantidad }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer una sumatoria dentro del ciclo del **`ngFor`** estilo "**`var x += p.cantidad`**" y mostrarla al final del mismo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solo voy a complementar un poco con respecto al comentario de Enrique.

**¿Qué es *ngFor en Angular?**

`ngFor` es una directiva estructural, lo que significa que cambia la estructura del DOM.
El punto es repetir una plantilla HTML dada una vez para cada valor en una matriz, cada vez que le pase el valor de la matriz como contexto para la interpolación o enlace de cadenas.

Dicho esto, lo máximo que podrías hacer dentro de un `ngFor` es realizar cálculos básicos (*, /, -, --) dentro de una misma fila, pero no como lo pretendes (si fue que entendí bien tu pregunta), que es calcular la suma total de de una columna.

Para realizar esto, debes de hacerlo desde tu cliente del componente `typescript` en el que requieres realizar los respectivos calculos. Voy a mostrarte un breve ejemplo de `x` personas que han comprado `y` producto por cierta cantidad, mostrando en la misma fila el saldo total de la venta y por fuera del `ngFor` realizamos la suma de lo que nos adeudan `z` clientes:

**Ejemplo HTML**

```
<h4>NgFor</h4>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>Costo(Und)</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Saldo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let persona of personas, index as id">
      <td>{{ id+1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ persona.nombre_persona }}</td>
      <td>{{ persona.apellido_persona }}</td>
      <td>{{ persona.nombre_producto}}</td>
      <td>{{ persona.costo_producto | currency}}</td>
      <td>{{ persona.cantidad_producto}}</td>
      <td>{{ persona.costo_producto * persona.cantidad_producto | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
    <hr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>{{ total | currency }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

**Ejemplo Typescript**

```
export class AppComponent  
{
  name = 'Angular';
  total:number;

  ngOnInit() 
  {
    //Calculamos el TOTAL 
    this.total = this.personas.reduce((
      acc,
      obj,
    ) => acc + (obj.costo_producto * obj.cantidad_producto),
    0);
    console.log("Total: ", this.total)
  }
  personas: any[] = [
    {
      'nombre_persona': 'Felipe',
      'apellido_persona':'Fernandes',
      'nombre_producto':'Computador',
      'cantidad_producto':'5',
      'costo_producto':'25000',
    },
    {
      'nombre_persona': 'Juan',
      'apellido_persona':'Suarez',
      'nombre_producto':'Equipo de Sonido',
      'cantidad_producto':'1',
      'costo_producto':'35000',
    },
    {
      'nombre_persona': 'Raul',
      'apellido_persona':'Aveiro',
      'nombre_producto':'Celular',
      'cantidad_producto':'2',
      'costo_producto':'150000',
    },
    {
      'nombre_persona': 'Humberto',
      'apellido_persona':'Castilla',
      'nombre_producto':'Toner de Impresora',
      'cantidad_producto':'15',
      'costo_producto':'12000',
    },
  ];
}
```

Esto, fue solo un ejemplo con el operador de multiplicación entre dos objetos de la matriz, podrías utilizar multiples objetos y diferentes operadores para hallar algún resultado.

[image: Imagen del demo]

Si te es complejo verlo desde aquí, te he realizado un [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/suma-total?file=src/app/app.component.html) en línea para que lo puedas ver el funcionamiento. Si tienes alguna duda no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: ¡me sirvio excelente! muchisimas gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

El ngFor no está diseñado para cálculos, lo correcto es calcularlo en el componente

```
ngOnInit(){
const sum = pista.pistas.reduce((actual, anterior) => return actual + anterior);

}
```

después en el template simplemente muestras el valor donde quieras usando {{sum}}