# Sumar valor campo ngFor

Tags: nodejs, angular, mongodb, ngfor

Como puedo obtener el total de la suma total de varios campos de un ngFor

Tengo este array con dos items

```
 "items": [
    {
        "completado": false,
        "_id": "5d39f5bcc4304837dc9ea5a2",
        "nombre_item": "Item 2",
        "number": 25,
        "repo": "5d385f8afc5b8e1690af7b31",
        "createdAt": "2019-07-25T18:32:28.372Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-07-25T18:32:28.372Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "completado": false,
        "_id": "5d39fbc3e78e2c2020df3b77",
        "nombre_item": "Item 1",
        "number": 50,
        "repo": "5d385f8afc5b8e1690af7b31",
        "createdAt": "2019-07-25T18:58:11.251Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-07-25T18:58:11.251Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

La idea es mostrar el total de el array que obtengo, en este caso sumar los dos campos "number" que seria el total de "75".

```
<table>
  <tr  ngFor="item of items">
    <td>{{item.nombre_item}}</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<p>{{sumaTotal}}</p>
```

EDIT: 
NO entiendo que se de como duplicada ya que el enlace muestra como sumar dos campos dentro de un array y no es lo que intento hacer.
En mi caso quiero sumar dentro del array todos los campos X para que me de un total. Es posible que no me haya explicado bien. 
De igual forma agrego ahi la solucion para mi caso en la que tuve que modificar mi backend para obtener dicho resultado, fue lo mas facil

```
Item.aggregate([
                {$group:{
                    _id: null,
                    totalValue: {$sum: "$number"}
                }}
            ],(err, total)=>{
                res.status(201).json({
                    ok: true,
                    total
                });
            })
```

Comment: Deberías hacer la operación en tu archivo js, crear una variable y asignarle dicho resultado mediante un loop, un map, etc

Comment: Hola @Federico, esta pregunta se puede marcar como duplicada, dado que ya hay respuesta para ella, por lo tanto te invito a que la mires y si es el caso que la marques como positivo [aquí (incluye un ejemplo en Stackblitz)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/209772/sumar-valores-dentro-de-ngfor/209870#209870)

Answer (score 1):

dentro de tu archivo ts crea una función que se encargue de manejar dicho comportamiento

```
sumaTotalFunction():void{
   this.items.map(x =>
      this.sumaTotal += x.number
   )
}
```

Y esta ejecutarla justamente despues de que tus items esten cargados.